# translation invariance of expectation value of hit counting variable for Lévy process

Tags: stochastic-processes, levy-processes

Let $(X_t)_{t \in [0, \infty)}$ a $\mathbb{R}$- valued
Markov process, $s, a, u >0$,
$I(a) := 
\{[k \cdot a, (k+1) \cdot a] \ : \ k \in \mathbb{Z} \} $ the
family of $a$-integral tiles covering $\mathbb{R}$.
Let $M_u(a,s)$ the random variable counting the number of tiles
$[k \cdot a, (k+1) \cdot a]$ in $I(a)$ hit by
$(X_t)$ at some time $t \in [u,u+s]$. The
notion is introduced in the paper
"Hausdorff Dimension Theorems for Self-Similar Markov Processes"
by Luqin Liu and Yimin Xiao in lemma 3.1 for Markov processes.

My question is if for
$(X_t)_{t \in [0, \infty)}$ a $\mathbb{R}$- valued
Lévy process the expectation value of $M_u(a,s)$ is
"translation invariant" in the sense that

$$\mathbb{E}[M_u(a,s)]= \mathbb{E}[M_0(a,s)] $$

i.e. the expectation value of the number of hit tiles
$[k \cdot a, (k+1) \cdot a]$ in $I(a)$ from $I(a)$ by
$(X_t)$ at some time $t \in [u,u+s]$ is the same as
the expectation value of the number of hit by
$(X_t)$ at some time $t \in [0,s]$?