# Non-deterministic bounded Lévy process

Tags: stochastic-processes, levy-processes

Does there exist a non-deterministic
$\mathbb{R}$- valued Lévy process
$(X_t)_{t \in [0, \infty)}$ such that there exist a
$t_0 \in (0, \infty) $ and $R>0$ such that

$$ P(0 < X_{t_0} < R)=1 $$

i.e. $X_{t_0}$ is almost surely positive and bounded by $R$.

Since Lévy processes are more or less generated by infinitely divisible
random variables, this rases the question if there exist a non-deterministic
$\mathbb{R}$- valued infinitely divisible random variable
(i.e. it's density measure
$\mu_X$ is infinitely divisible with respect convolution) such that
there exist $R>0$ with $ P(0 < X_{t_0} < R)=1 $; equivalently,
$\mu_X((0,R))=1$.

The question is motivated by the problem here:
[translation invariance of expectation value of hit counting variable for Lévy process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4866499/translation-invariance-of-expectation-value-of-hit-counting-variable-for-l%c3%a9vy-pr)

I'm seeking to construct a counterexample with a
$\mathbb{R}$- valued Lévy process
$(X_t)_{t \in [0, \infty)}$ such that there exist $s,a,u>0$ with

$$\mathbb{E}[M_u(a,s)]= \mathbb{E}[M_0(a,s)] $$

where $M_u(a,s)$ the random variable counting the number of tiles
$[k \cdot a, (k+1) \cdot a]$ in $I(a):=
\{[k \cdot a, (k+1) \cdot a] \ : \ k \in \mathbb{Z} \} $
hit by
$(X_t)$ at some time $t \in [u,u+s]$.

Obviously, finding such Lévy process $(X_t)_{t \in [0, \infty)}$
containing an a.s. positive and bounded member $X_{t_0}$ as above would do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**An answer to your actual question:** No.

Thus, suppose that $(X_t)$ is a Lévy process with $X_0=0$ and $0<X_{t_0}<R$ a.s., for some $t_0>0$ and some finite $R>0$.

I assume without loss of generality that $t_0=1$.

**Claim:** $X_t>0$ for all $t>0$ a.s.

Indeed, for positive integer $n$, $P(X_n>0)\ge\left(P(X_1>0)\right)^n=1$. Consider now $X_{1/2}$. If we had $P(X_{1/2}\le 0)>0$, then we would have
$P(X_1\le 0)\ge \left( P(X_{1/2}\le 0)\right)^2>0$, a contradiction.
Therefore $P(X_{1/2}>0)=1$ as well. Proceeding recursively, $P(X_{2^{-k}}>0)=1$ for all $k=1,2,\ldots$. In combination with the first sentence of this paragraph this shows that $P(X_{k2^{-n}}>0)=1$ for all positive integer $k$ and $n$; by countable additivity,
$$
P(X_s>0,\hbox{ for all dyadic rational }s>0)=1.\qquad (1)
$$
Because the paths of a Lévy process are right continuous, we deduce from (1) that
$$
P(X_t\ge 0,\forall t>0)=1.\qquad (2)
$$
It is known that for a non-negative Lévy process, the Laplace transform $E(\exp(-\lambda X_t))$, $\lambda>0$, takes the form $\exp(-t\psi(\lambda)$, where
$$
\psi(\lambda) =b\lambda +\int_{(0,\infty)}(1-e^{-\lambda x})\nu(dx),\qquad (3)
$$
for a constant $b\ge 0$ and a measure $\nu$ such that $\int_{(0,\infty)}(x\wedge 1)\nu(dx)<\infty$. Using (3),
$$
P(X_t=0)=\lim_{\lambda\to+\infty}e^{-t\psi(\lambda)}.\qquad (4)
$$
From (1), the limit in (4) is $0$ if $t$ is a dyadic rational, so in fact it must be $0$ for every $t>0$. Thus
$$
P(X_t>0,\forall t>0)=1.\qquad (5)
$$

By virtue of the Claim,
The process $(X_t)$ has non-decreasing sample paths; as such it admits a Lévy-Ito decomposition. In particular,
$$
X_1=b+\sum_{0<s\le 1} \Delta X_s,
$$
where $\Delta X_s:=X_s-X_{s-}\ge 0$, and the sum in (6) is a countable sum over those times $s\in (0,1]$ for which $\Delta X_s>0$. The crucial point here is that for $\epsilon>0$ the number $J(\epsilon)$ of $s\in(0,1]$ such that $\Delta X_s >\epsilon$ has the Poisson distribution with parameter $\nu(\epsilon,\infty)$. Assuming that $(X_t)$ is non-deterministic, we can choose $\epsilon$ such that $\nu(\epsilon,\infty)>0$. Now choose a positive integer $K$ such that $K>R/\epsilon$. Then $P(J(\epsilon)=K)>0$ and on the event $\{J(\epsilon)=K\}$ we have
$$
X_1\ge\epsilon\cdot J(\epsilon)=\epsilon\cdot K > R.
$$
That is, $P(X_1>R)>0$. There is no non-deterministic Lévy process with $P(0<X_{t_0}<R)=1$ for even one time $t_0$.

Consequently,  there is no no-trivial positive infinitely divisible random variable that is (a.s.) bounded.

Answer (score 1):

No. (I presume that $X_0=0$.)

Under your hypothesis there exists $\epsilon\in(0,R)$ such that
$c:=P(X_{t_0}>\epsilon)>0$.
Then for positive integer $n$,
$$
P(X_{nt_0}>n\epsilon)\ge c^n>0.
$$
Now choose $n$ so large that $n\epsilon >R$ to see that $P(X_{nt_0}>R)>0$. In short, $X$ isn't a.s. bounded above.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but your argument shows that $X$ (as whole(!) Lévy process $(X_t)_{t \in [0, \infty)}$) cannot be bounded in the sense that there exist no $S>0$ such that for all $t \in (0, \infty]$ holds $X_t <S$ a.s., right? My question was if it might happen for a non-deterministic $\mathbb{R}$-valued Lévy process $(X_t)_{t \in [0, \infty)}$there exist a $t_0 \in (0, \infty]$ such that $X_{t_0}$ is bounded a.s., in the sense that there exist  a $t_0 \in (0, \infty]$ for which exists a $R:=R(t_0)>0$ such that $0 <X_{t_0} < R$ a.s., but only for this one $t_0$.

Comment: That is I asked if there exist one $t_0 \in (t, \infty]$ such that that $X$ is bounded at this $t_0$, not if the whole process is bounded, which cannot be the case as your argument above shows.

Comment: BTW: As I described above my question is equivalent to if there exist a non-deterministic positive real valued *infinitely divisible* random variable $Z$, which is bounded.